# Splicing sections of words to make a new word

Tags: python, splice

I am getting the correct word for this but how do I make it a coherent sentence. Currently it has spaces between each variable.

- What I get is : `NIC E J ob!`
- What I want is: `Nice Job!`

```
import string
x = "NICK" # First 3 characters
y = "DE JAVU" # 1 to 4 characters
z = "Bob!" # Last 3 characters

x1 = x[0:3]
y1 = y[1:4]
z1 = z[-3:]


def main():
    print(x1,y1,z1)

main()
```

Comment: And what sort of rules do you think you need to get from one to the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = "NICK" # First 3 characters
y = "DE JAVU" # 1 to 4 characters
z = "Bob!" # Last 3 characters


def main():
    raw_line = x[0:3] + y[1:4] + z[-3:]
    result = " ".join(map(str.capitalize, raw_line.split()))
    print(result)

main()
```

```
>>> 'Nice Job!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok, but `print()` adds space between the printed variables. Use `sep=''` parameter in `print()`:

```
import string
x = "NICK" # First 3 characters
y = "DE JAVU" # 1 to 4 characters
z = "Bob!" # Last 3 characters

x1 = x[0:3]
y1 = y[1:4]
z1 = z[-3:]


def main():
    print(x1,y1,z1, sep='')

main()
```

Prints:

```
NICE Job!
```

Answer (score 0):

The  [`print (doc)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) method joins the different parameter with a space as default, but you can change it with the `sep` parameter

```
print(x1, y1, z1, sep='')
```

You can also just concatenate the different parts

```
print(x1 + y1 + z1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the join method on a string object. It takes an iterable and, well, joins stuff.

```
output = "".join((x1, y1, z1))
```

If you want to capitalise the strings and play with the case... again, the string object has methods

```
output.capitalize()
```